# View Input Text for a second in TextBox and change to passwordchar

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

same [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626937/how-to-show-in-wpf-password-box-characters-for-few-second) as this one but the last answer is the one i wanted.. I need c# wpf... i tried the last answer but i can't seem to get the interval.. sometimes the key pressed can be seen, and sometimes it doesn't.. how can I get same interval when key press?

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

i tried

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

but still the same...

**EDIT**

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < txtPass.Text.Length; i++)
        str += char.ConvertFromUtf32(8226);

    txtPass.Text = str;
    txtPass.Select(txtPass.Text.Length, 0);
}
```

Comment: Linking to another question doesn't prevent you to ask it. + we need to see `dispatcherTimer_Tick`'s implementation.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I suggest you do `txtPass.Text = new string(char.ConvertFromUtf32(8226), txtPass.Text.Length);`, regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to subscribe to new event handler every time. Just do it one time in the constructor

```
dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

In the `Keydown` event, just reset the `timer` (Unfortunately we don't have any `Reset` method)

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

As the timer ticks, just `Stop` the timer and do your work

```
void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    //your code
}
```

Comment: @Yorye Nathan, what's that suppose to mean?

Comment: how can i make the password visible? or change it to text?