# Read masked password and check if available in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a problem logging in, because of the masked password that i made [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092584/view-input-text-for-a-second-in-textbox-and-change-to-passwordchar). I realized that, i tried masking the password but then the database cannot read my password.

Example:

My password is admin, but the one that is sent to my database to check is just "••••"

Can anyone please help me, im still new at this...

Comment: The same process to transform data when saving to Db should be the same applied  to the password that the user provides when logging to check for a match. We usually store hash password in the Db, when the user logs in, we hash the provided password and compare with the hashed one in Db. In your case, you can consider your masking function the hash function.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand... if i just use passwordbox, i can simply connect to the database.. but then i programmatically masked the password using a textbox, then it cant be read because it simply read •••• how can i make the program read the masked password in my situation?

Comment: When you mask a password ,try to keep the original password in a variable and use that to connect to the Db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is that you have to keep a string variable for password.As the user types the password display the masked character on screen but concat each character read to the string and at last that will be your passwors.There is no need to store the masked password as it is useless to store it.