# Use a TextBox as a PasswordBox. WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a login form with two textboxes, one for username and one for password.

I have used a textbox for the password input, however I would like to mask the characters so that rather than showing letters, it will show a (*) symbol or a password dot.

I can not change the textbox to a password box as this throws errors.

Using C#, WPF form

Comment: can you explain what errors you are running into?

Comment: there appear to be solutions (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6629237/1132334) but they all look far more complicated than using a password box. would it be worth to sort out that "pool of errors" instead? has it something to do with the `PasswordBox` not inheriting from `TextBox`?

Comment: @dlatikay for example, I am using a SQL database to retrieve the users login details. However, when I use "passwordBox.Text" to retrieve the input from the password box i get errors.

Comment: have you tried passwordBox.Password?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Rogan What errors are you getting, exactly? Also, are you using the MVVM pattern or any data-binding, or are you doing it old-school (like WinForms) where your code directly reads and assigns control properties?

Comment: The `PasswordBox` does not inherit from `TextBox`. Its content is accessible via the `Password` and `SecurePassword` properties, and that's for a reason, see also [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox(v=vs.110).aspx)
do some research, there are at least three googleable SO posts on the topic/add the compiler+runtime errors you get to your question.

Comment: question solved using @dlatikay comment. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the PasswordBox and rewriting your code to work with that instead of coming up with a work around. I am not exactly sure what error you are getting, but you can get the value of the PasswordBox almost the same way as getting the value/text from a TextBox.

TextBox:

```
TextBox1.Text
```

PasswordBox:

```
PasswordBox1.Password
PasswordBox1.SecurePassword
```

Answer (score -1):

In your xaml file:

```
<TextBlock Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name ="Pwderrormessage"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Margin="0,347,60,0" 
           OpacityMask="Crimson" Foreground="#FFE5572C" />

<Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Content="Password:" Foreground="White"
       TextBlock.FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Margin="230,340,0,0" Height="30" Width="84"/>

<StackPanel Height="23" Width="200" Margin="126,170,0,0">
   <PasswordBox x:Name="txtpwd" PasswordChar="*" Height="23" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And code behind page inside the button click event handler:

```
if (txtpwd.Password.Length == 0)
{
    Pwderrormessage.Text = "Enter a Password.";
    txtpwd.Focus();
}
else
{
    /*Save you data*/
}
```

Comment: don't use snippet when your code can't execute here